# Fallback for all pages regardless URL parameters?

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I have following FALLBACK section in manifest

```
FALLBACK:
*.php offline.html
/ offline.html
*/* offline.html
```

I'm trying it with Firefox and its Work offline feature. This works for any URL like pageA.php, pageB.php etc. But when I enter URL like this

```
pageA.php?parameter=1&ddd=2
```

Then the offline page is not displayed and only warning message is shown:

> Firefox is currently in offline mode and can't browse the Web

Any ideas how to modify the manifest so URL with parameters will be fallbacked to offline.html as well?